# Android video gallery

Tags: android, video, gallery

I've been searching on here all morning for some direction, and i'll admit i probably haven't tried hard enough. Anyways can someone point me in the right direction as to how i can make the gallery display video that a person just shot from their phone. Does it save to the sd card or a libraries on the phone? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code example](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)